# Strange code behavior in C while using pointers where commenting a certain unrelated section of the code affects the output

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

The following code written by me shows strange behavior depending on whether I 'comment' the third and fourth line or not, in the `main()` function. If I 'comment' the `printf` and `scanf` statements, the code behaves as expected, otherwise it produces unexpected result/output.
Please help me as to what I'm missing. Basically, I'm just a C newbie trying to understand pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int n, *ptr1;
    char ch, *ptr2;
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter any single alphabetic character\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    ptr1 = &n;
    ptr2 = &ch;
    printf("\nThe integer is %d and its pointer is %d in the address %d\n", n, *ptr1, ptr1);
    printf("\nThe character is %c and its pointer is %c in the address %d\n", ch, *ptr2, ptr2);
}
```

Comment: What is this expected and unexpected output? Always include all necessary information.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&ch);` => `scanf(" %c",&ch);` else previous scanf makes it so `ch <- newline`

Comment: there are too many mistakes here for us to fix it.

Comment: Combien des fautes,  Monsieur? Expliquez s'il vous plait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that when you insert an integer, you input a newline character, which is considered as a character and inserted into ch variable. Add the leading whitespace to the second scanf call to ignore the previous newline.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,*ptr1;
    char ch,*ptr2;
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter any single alphabetic character\n");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);// <- space added

    ptr1=&n;
    ptr2=&ch;
    printf("\nThe integer is %d and its pointer is %d in the address %p\n", n, *ptr1, (void*) ptr1);
    printf("\nThe character is %c and its pointer is %c in the address %p\n",ch, *ptr2, (void*) ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Working session:

```
Enter an integer
6
Enter any single alphabetic character
b

The integer is 6 and its pointer is 6 in the address 0x22cc84

The character is b and its pointer is b in the address 0x22cc83
```

PS. Don't use `conio.h` - it is non-standard, and some compilers don't support it. Plus you don't call any functions from it.

Comment: @chqrlie Done, added return 0 at the end. Now it's nice.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer.. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%p` to print a pointer value.

```
printf("\nThe integer is %d and its pointer is %d in the address %p\n",n,*ptr1,(void *)ptr1);
printf("\nThe character is %c and its pointer is %c in the address %p\n",ch,*ptr2,(void *)ptr2);
```

If you comment out the two lines you mentioned, `n` will be uninitialized.

[Demo](https://tio.run/##bZDBasMwEETv/orFJSEObiG@tuktf5BjLpuVai24ayGphVD67c5argMF6bCg0eybQfTcE03TEwsNX8a@xWR4fHHv1ffIBj6RZddUPxXoYUkg7d6ncHjNAjkMOrLULZIP6vrY1SdJNgDKvGR7Gy5SN4sjEooaNqZut9KUt24QWfrBAg7e4dUmphyGlEooUhS5laX1jlt5XLqjvv2PucjZ2bUZcISN0VADnCL4kXOJRWWBpFY0Jtioitfw9u8P2nk0JfKjaqZQkU1l9vqbM7xT@O80HfAO)